# JAXB alternative for @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter

Tags: jaxb, jackson

I have my class annotated to accept extra elements in JSON, like this:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    private final Map<String, Object> map;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> map() {
        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        return map.put(key, value);
    }
```

When I deserialize a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : "qux"
}
```

I creates a map with key, value pairs foo, bar and baz, qux.
I would like this class to work for JAXB as well, so that I can serialize/deserialize to JSON and to XML. So this xml should be deserialized to the same map:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
<baz>qux</baz>
```

I started off with Jackson for a pure JSON mapping, which is working with the annotations as shown. How can I archieve the same result for XML?

Comment: Jackson has an extension for serializing POJOs as XML (and deserializing from XML) https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: JAXB has [@XmlAnyElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) and [@XmlAnyAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html), which are somewhat similar.